# Show that $\vec\nabla\times(\vec\nabla\times\vec A )=- \nabla^ 2\vec A + \vec\nabla (\vec\nabla\cdot\vec A )$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis, vector-fields, divergence-operator, curl

I just started learning this and I don't understand much so how can I prove this?
$$\vec\nabla\times(\vec\nabla\times\vec A )=-\vec\nabla^2\vec A +\vec\nabla (\vec\nabla\cdot\vec A )$$

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: What have you tried?  Have you attempted a brute force approach by carrying out the derivatives?

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1108604/583883

Comment: You can do it with Levi-Civita symbol

Answer (score 0):

$\def\n{\nabla}$The vector aspect can be addressed using the triple product (aka bac-cab) rule $a\times(b\times c) = b\,(a\cdot c)- c\,(a\cdot b)$, but the derivative aspect requires keeping the $\n$ operator on the LHS of each expression
$\eqalign{\n\times(\n\times c)
 &= \n\big(\n\cdot c\big)- \big(\n\cdot \n\big)\,c \\
 &= \n\big(\n\cdot c\big)- \n^2c \\
}$